# Key generation missing in Google Chrome. How to get it back?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

**In the Google Chrome Content settings there was "Key generation" option to generate keys in the web forms.** See the screenshots from the [question about Key generation](https://superuser.com/questions/1097778/what-is-key-generation-in-google-chrome/1136378). This is required by one Comodo SSL re-seller. Without it I can not generate my SSL certificates.

I am using Google Chrome versions 57.0.2987.98 and 57.0.2987.110 (64-bit). **And the setting is now gone.** When I try to issue the SSL, Comodo website shows "Sorry, an error has occurred" without any details.

**How to get Key generation back to Google Chrome?**

Comment: I am going to presume, that we are talking about the [key generation element](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5716060992962560), and it was removed in Chrome 57.  Having checked a copy of Chrome 56, i can confirm, it also did not have it.  So outside of using a previous version of Chrome, contact your Comodo re-seller, and request an alternative method to generate your SSL certificates.  My suggestion, find a different re-seller, one that doesn't use a defuct feature of Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Worth pointing out.  The current version of Firefox does support it behind a user gesture.  IE/Edge have never supported it.  So another solution is to use a browser or a previous version of Chrome that supports it.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the info. And I can not change the re-seller because I have a couple SSL's there and I can generate new certs that are SHA-2 instead of SHA-1 for free, so currently trying with Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Key Generation was a part of the implementation of the < keygen > HTML element. This has been removed from the W3C spec and it was accordingly removed from Chrome/Chromium browsers.

If you want to see what support remains for < keygen > take a look at https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/475/0/which-browser-can-i-use-to-signup-for-a-email-certificate

Comment: https://knowledge.digicert.com/generalinformation/keygenfirefox.html